# Vue conditionals for binding classes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how to bind classes to a table row conditionally based on a vue model.

IN my blade I have:

```
.low-priority{
    background-color: purple;
}
.high-priority{
    background-color: orange;
}
.important-priority{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.critical-priority{
    background-color: red;
}
```

and in my vue template I return a `dateEvents` object which has a value called `priority` which can be `"High"`, `"Low"`, `"Important"` or `"Critical"`.

I want to set the class of this table row by those priorities:

```
<tr v-bind:class="dateEvent">
```

I've seen the docs for binding a class if a return is true or false, but how do I do this appropriately with conditionals, i.e. `if dateEvent.priority === 'Low' then class is .low-priority'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you need a conditional in this case:

```html
<tr :class="`${dateEvent.priority.toLowerCase()}-priority`">
```

Or if you don't like backticks:

```html
<tr :class="dateEvent.priority.toLowerCase() + '-priority'">
```

A more general solution would be to use a computed property. In the circumstances that would be a bit repetitive though.

```html
<tr :class="rowClass">
```

```js
computed: {
  rowClass () {
    const priority = this.dateEvent.priority

    return {
      'low-priority': priority === 'Low',
      'high-priority': priority === 'High',
      'important-priority': priority === 'Important',
      'critical-priority': priority === 'Critical'
    }
  }
}
```

If `dateEvents` isn't available via `this` because it's a loop parameter (i.e. from `v-for`) then you'd make `rowClass` a method instead and pass in `dateEvents` from the template.

Other variations on that theme are available: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html