# Vue Conditional Class Binding

Tags: class, vue.js, conditional-binding

I am trying to dynamically render class based off actionTypeCreate. This is a method that simply returns a boolean value based off the prop actionType that is passed. I am triggering this method on the mounted hook and confirmed it is returning properly.

Now I am trying to return the class value of 'col-md-4' if actionTypeCreate. If not actionTypeCreate I want to return the class 'col-md-6'.

This is what I have but it is not working:

```
:class="{toggleActionType : 'col-md-4' ? 'col-md-6'}"
```

I tried to reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592280/vue-conditionals-for-binding-classes) existing question, but I did not get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) itself you can do it in two ways. First, you can use **Array Syntax** and this is **broadly used to apply a list of classes**.

**Array Syntax**

```js
:class="[toggleActionType ? 'col-md-4' : 'col-md-6']"
```

Or you can do it as normal by Object Syntax but it does not accept ternary operations, so you have to do it this way:

**Object Syntax**

```js
:class="{'col-md-4' : toggleActionType , 'col-md-6' : !toggleActionType}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
:class="{'col-md-4' : toggleActionType , 'col-md-6' : !toggleActionType }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:class="[toggleActionType : 'col-md-4' ? 'col-md-6']"
```